# Async socket for streaming server

Tags: c, sockets, freebsd

I’m trying to build a streaming server using sockets with C language.

First I tried linux and io_uring. It works ok but only for small files (~ 2 MB). With io_uring I’ve managed to do async read/write to socket.

Then I’ve read about FreeBSD and Kqueue so I decided to give it a try and I need some help with understanding on how can I do async read/write to socket. As I understand Kqueue allows you to do async accept new connections but how do you async read/write to socket on FreeBSD. Maybe aio_read() and aio_read() would help in this case or there is a better way?

Comment: Unix systems traditionally *don't have* async read and write. What makes you sure that FreeBSD has it?

Answer (score 2):

> First I tried linux and io_uring. It works ok but only for small files (~ 2 MB). With io_uring I’ve managed to do async read/write to socket.

I'm inclined to guess that you could find ways to make io_uring work better for you.

> I’ve read about FreeBSD and Kqueue so I decided to give it a try and I need some help with understanding on how can I do async read/write to socket.

At least as it applies to I/O, kqueue is basically an alternative to `select()` and `poll()`.  These all provide ways to multiplex *synchronous* I/O with multiple remote peers, but they are not especially applicable to async I/O.

> As I understand Kqueue allows you to do async accept new connections

Not exactly.  Kqueue allows you to determine which listening sockets have connections ready to be accepted, so that you can `accept()` those (synchronously) without risk of blocking.

> but how do you async read/write to socket on FreeBSD

If you're looking to use Kqueue, then it can also tell you which connected sockets at any given time can be read from and / or written to (synchronously) without blocking.  That (and `select()`, and `poll()`) allow you to use one or a small number of threads to serve a larger number of concurrent clients, but this is all synchronous, not async.

If you want a genuine asynchronous I/O interface, then yes, `aio_read()` and `aio_write()` can serve.  On Linux, too.  I'm not inclined to expect that to be fundamentally any better than io_uring, but you may find more resources to help you use `aio_read()` and `aio_write()` effectively than to help you with (very new) `io_uring`.

Comment: Linux AIO just does the IO on another thread. No different than if you did that yourself.

Comment: Yes, @user253751, and what? The requested I/O is performed asynchronously with respect to the thread that calls `aio_read()` / `aio_write()`.  That's "a genuine asynchronous I/O interface".  Contrast with I/O multiplexing via `select()` / `poll()` / `Kqueue`, which is not.

Answer (score 0):

When it comes to API design, you won't get much better than what's available on Linux.

`io_uring` is by definition fully  asynchronous, but it still goes through the same hops as normal network I/O, and you need to ask for polling to avoid latency when idling, among other design considerations to maximise performance. In principle, there's no size limitations, but it's true that write calls are limited to 2 GB at a time (which is a lot anyway) on Linux.

If you want to get close to the raw NIC performance, you should try XDP instead, which bypasses the network stack, but of course you need to do your own thing, as you won't have the sockets API at your disposal.

Which issue did you run into when transferring 2 MB of data?

Comment: When I start testing I started with small files (10 kb) then a little bigger file (100 kb) then 200 kb then 1 mb and file was successfully received by chunks of 512 bytes. When I tried to receive file with size 2 mb receiver stuck on receiving and I don’t know what is the reason.

Comment: What was your debugging approach? What did the completion for the write contain on the writer side?